# Unauthorized credit checks run by used car dealers. Can they do this, and what can I do?

Tags: credit, credit-report

I've been shopping for used cars and it seems that the used car dealers have been running credit checks without my permission.  After about a month I noticed them on my credit report.

What is the best way to get these removed from my credit report?  Seems like other people are having the same issue.

http://badfinance.org/review/2144775/experian-credit-reporting

Comment: I was just wondering, in the States, the fact that someone (example, car dealer) merely *runs a credit check* - that affects your credit score adversely?  How so?  What's the idea there?

Comment: What happens usually is that your score takes a bit of a hit when a creditor pulls your credit and then there's no corresponding account opened.  The scoring models are a closely-guarded secret, but I think they're designed to assume that there's a reason a creditor pulled your report and then decided not to offer a credit line to you.

Comment: Edit needed:  How did they get your SSN?  I feel like you filled out a form that authorized the pull.

Comment: Many, many years ago it's apparent a car dealer did a credit check on my wife.  She filled out **nothing**, they had only her "name" & my address.  While I do not know who did it I know what must have happened because they got it wrong.  The thing is in casual matters she goes by an American name rather than her true foreign name.  Of course there were no hits--but it's just close enough to my name that I ended up with her listed as an alias of me!

Answer (score 10):

Well, the obvious first step is to contact the credit bureau which is reporting the "hard pull" on your credit and inform them that you did not authorize the inquiry.  As with any other credit dispute, the bureau should then contact the dealer(s) and require them to show proof of your authorization for those inquiries.

***Be careful, though.***  My guess is that somewhere along the line, the dealer (maybe in *very tiny writing* somewhere) got you to agree to an inquiry without actually coming out and saying that's what they were going to do, in which case you may have to go to a different step.

It seems to me that state and/or federal laws prohibit the practice of pulling your credit without express consent, in which case you could have grounds for civil action against the dealer(s).  There may also be criminal laws which have been broken.  Here's an [article from CreditCards.com](http://www.creditcards.com/credit-card-news/illegal-credit_report-access-1282.php) about this very subject, and it might be a worthwhile read for you.

Here's [an article from NoLo.com](http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/impermissible-credit-report-use.html) about impermissible use of credit inquiries that's very interesting.

If, as you state, this was done without your consent then there are PLENTY of legal remedies at your disposal.  Just be certain beforehand that you know without doubt you did not authorize the inquiries, and you should prevail.

I hope this helps.

Good luck!